# Why do I get an Error/a Filesystem Exception when update Composer by self-update?

Tags: windows, installation, composer-php

I just did a routine check of the level of composer on my PC and got some unexpected messages:

```
composer -V
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/HelperSet.php on line 112

Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/HelperSet.php on line 112
Deprecation Notice: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of 
type string is deprecated in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/Constraint.php:48
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:277
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:277
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:277
Deprecation Notice: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of 
type string is deprecated in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/Constraint.php:48
Composer version 2.0.7 2020-11-13 17:31:06
```

I decided that my easiest course of action would be to update Composer since this version is now 2 years old so I ran the command to do so but got the same deprecation messages and an actual error:

```
composer self-update
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/HelperSet.php on line 112

Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/HelperSet.php on line 112
Deprecation Notice: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of 
type string is deprecated in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/Constraint.php:48
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:277
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:277
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:277
Deprecation Notice: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of 
type string is deprecated in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/Constraint.php:48
Deprecation Notice: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of 
type string is deprecated in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/Constraint.php:48
Deprecation Notice: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of 
type string is deprecated in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/Constraint.php:48
Upgrading to version 2.4.4 (stable channel).
   


  [Composer\Downloader\FilesystemException]
  Filesystem exception:                                                 
  Composer update failed: "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.   
  phar" could not be written.                                           
  rename(C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin/composer-temp.phar,C:\Progr   
  amData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar): Access is denied (code: 5)   
                                                                        

self-update [-r|--rollback] [--clean-backups] [--no-progress] [--update-keys] [--stable] [--preview] [--snapshot] [--1] [--2] [--set-channel-only] [--] [<version>]
```

Both of the files involved in the rename are present in C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin, namely composer.phar and composer-temp.phar so I suppose the error is legitimate: the new name for composer-temp.phar is already in use.

What do I do here? Rename composer.phar to composer.phar.old and then try the self-update again? Or will that cause other problems?

---

Output from **`composer diagnose`**:

```
composer diagnose
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/HelperSet.php on line 112

Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/HelperSet.php on line 112
Deprecation Notice: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of 
type string is deprecated in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/Constraint.php:48
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:277
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:277
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:277
Deprecation Notice: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of 
type string is deprecated in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/Constraint.php:48
Deprecation Notice: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of 
type string is deprecated in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/Constraint.php:48
Deprecation Notice: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of 
type string is deprecated in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/Constraint.php:48
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: You are not running the latest stable version, run `composer self-update` to update (2.0.7 => 2.4.4)
Composer version: 2.0.7
PHP version: 8.1.5
PHP binary path: C:\xampp\php\php.exe
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
cURL version: 7.77.0 libz 1.2.12 ssl OpenSSL/1.1.1n
zip extension: OK
```

Comment: `composer diagnose` and add the output to your question.

Comment: `Composer version 2.0.7 2020-11-13 17:31:06` - thats a pretty old version of Composer, and  pretty recent version of PHP. Why not upgrade Composer?

Comment: @Nico Haase - Upgrading Composer is exactly what I'm trying to do but it's failing on the error you see in my post. Any idea why?

Comment: "Access is denied (code: 5) " - sounds like the permissions are wrong. How did you install Composer in the first place?

Comment: @Nico Haase - it was so long ago now that I'm no longer sure. I *think* I followed the Laravel6-from-scratch video at Laracasts. According to my very brief notes, it installed without difficulty. It never gave me any trouble while dabbling with Laravel in 2020.

Comment: Then why not try to install Composer once more?

Comment: @Nico Haase - I re-installed Composer and am now up to the current version 2.4.4. I was reluctant to re-install it if the "correct" approach was to do the self-update, for fear of messing something up but I suppose I should have just tried it. If you want to post your suggestion as a formal answer, I'll happily give you the points for a correct answer. Otherwise, thanks very much!

Comment: Just leaving an extensive answer, but this is not to grab trophies from Nico Haase who's comments helped you out of it. Just please check if the information would have been useful from your perspective and let me know how it could be improved @Henry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do I do here? Rename composer.phar to composer.phar.old and then try the self-update again? Or will that cause other problems?

You could have tried that and perhaps then would have found out that the composer command would not run any longer (as the phar file to execute is not at the expected place) and then you would perhaps copy over the temporary file (shown in the error message) and then it would have worked already.

The takeaway should be: You don't need to ask for permission on SO for doing so, as long as you remember what you did and can restore the previous situation in case it didn't compute, it's your system you have under control (at least to a certain extend as it is Windows but that is a different thing).

---

During your `composer self-update` (substract the noise from the deprecation notices<sup>1</sup>) Composer is running into a situation it can't solve without your intervention and therefore tells about it:

```
  [Composer\Downloader\FilesystemException]
  Filesystem exception:                                                 
  Composer update failed: "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.   
  phar" could not be written.                                           
  rename(C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin/composer-temp.phar,C:\Progr   
  amData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar): Access is denied (code: 5)
```

On the Windows Operating System (OS) this is commonly the case when Composer was installed with administrative rights or by a user with higher privileges than the user executing the `composer self-update` command.

> **INFO:** On Windows files may be locked until the next reboot of the system. This could not be levitated even with higher level privileges alone, and would require to reboot (with the proper timing beforehand) as well. Consult your operating system administration manual for the required procedures to provision program files, applications and their data for users of the system if you're concerned about this level of detail.

Either execute the `composer self-update` command with the needed privileges (the error message suggests writing to `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar` at least) or use the update procedure suggested by the original way of setting up composer on your system (e.g. `setup.exe`, `install.ini`, MSI package, some package manager if in use , etc., etc. etc.).

As you have not provided how you did install Composer or how Composer was installed on that system in the first place in your question, it can not be more specifically written out how this is done in your specific case.

Like you did, I'd also first go with `composer self-update` and then when getting that error perhaps *assume* that the [composer windows installer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows) was in use when setting up composer and then use that one to either update (if it provides) or re-install with it. However not without checking if that kind of setup was actually in use in the first place as otherwise I would do the update appropriate to the *original installation procedure*.

Composer is normally a handsome application therefore re-installing should normally do it and the composer windows setup takes care of a lot of windows specific configuration / setup things, so it adds even more assistance. But check first which installation procedure was in use, not that you end up with two different versions on the same system *unintentionally*.

E.g. one could check for the installer if it is available to uninstall composer under "programs" (that one within windows system configuration GUI). It has the benefit that if the setup provides such an option, not only uninstall but also update has a button to click.

> **WARNING:** A complete re-install of the system may therefore be the last option that is not mentioned so far, as it would render the original configuration void and you can "reboot" from a clean slate. Just mentioning it here as a warning, in case a reader may cross this idea, it is the most expensive option and should be avoided unless *all* other options did not compute.

---

1. Reg. the *noise from the deprecation notices*: Your [php-cli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.introduction.php) ini configuration has [display_errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) on, those are not errors, just informative or debugging notices. In your case it means you have updated PHP to a recent version, just the tooling with composer is not fully en-par with it. It may distract, but as long as only deprecation notices and warnings, composer should still be functional. So it does not look like those messages show the cause why composer can't do the `self-update` transaction on your system in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much! I know virtually nothing about Composer and had forgotten precisely how I installed it so had no idea how to proceed.

Comment: @Henry: IMHO you did everything right: first `composer self-update`  and then when seeing that error message looking forward to rename it by hand. I have no clue if that would have worked on your system (but you could have found out), that's merely all. I was under the impression that seeing that much noise when executing it may have distracted you from going on, may that be right?

Comment: And did you remembered now how you did install in the first place? If so, can you just comment again which one it was? A (re-) confirmation would be great.

Comment: I *think* I just followed the instructions in the Laravel 6 From Scratch course at Laracasts.

Comment: I am *almost* certain that I did the original install via the Windows installer and I *know* I did the reinstall via the Windows installer.